# What is this `Object[*]` type I get with COM interop?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I do C# excel interop. I call macros from C#, and I expect arrays of objects. I'm able to get 2-dimensional arrays of objects from the macros which returns 2-dimensional arrays.

However, an other (third party) macro is supposed to return a one-dimensional array. I can't get the `(object[])xlApp.Run(...)` working (it throws an exception), and the type info in the debugger says the result is of type `Object[*]`. The actual message from the exception is

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

What is this `Object[*]` type and how do I retrieve a one-dimensional array from this ?

**EDIT**: It occurred to me that this could mean a SAFEARRAY of VARIANTS. But then, two questions arise: why is everything ok with 2-dimensional arrays ? How do I convert a SAFEARRAY to a C# array ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I foulnd various articles about your problem :

[OPCFondation :](http://opcfoundation.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2221) Basically instead of declaring it as an array of objects, you can just declare it as an Array without providing any element type. So do not cast in Object[] but Array, and use a foreach loop to use the subarray.

```
foreach(object subobject in (Array)myarrayitem)
{
   //do stuff with the subobject, even browse further
}
```

This solution seems to work since you can find it again [here](http://www.dosadi.com/Forums/showthread.php?p=10527).

[On StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446/net-arrays-with-lower-bound-0) : they speak about arrays with lower bound > 0, which gives you the Object[*] type, with some links that can be interesting about the subject, but I think the first idea is the good one.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
System.Array a = (System.Array)((object)  returnedObject );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was such a PITA. I had this code in two projects:

```
Workbook wb = null;
try
{
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, false, true, 5, null, "WrongPAssword");
}
catch
{
    return false;
}    

try
{

    Array links = (Array)wb.LinkSources(XlLink.xlExcelLinks);
    if (links != null)
    {
```

One worked the other did not. The Difference. Working one was targeting .Net 2.0 and other one was .Net 4.0 that was giving the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type
>   'System.Object[]'.

Turns out if you change the Visual Studio version of this article from VS2005 to VS2010 the LinkSources datatype changes.

[MSDN Workbook.LinkSources Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.linksources%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

VS2010:

```
Object LinkSources(
    Object Type
)
```

VS2005:

```
public virtual Object LinkSources (
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Type
)
```