# How to get Excel XValue of a Chart in C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, charts

I am writing some codes to manipulate a chart in excle file using C#.  One of the key requirements is to get XValue property of a Chart SeriesCollection.  I tried to visit it by index, however it doesn't work, although I can see the value list in Watch window in Visual Studio.  From the Watch window, I noticed the type of s.XValue is **dynamic{object[]}** which I never met before, and obj.ToString() is **System.Object[*]**.  The question is how I can get each value from XValue property if XValue DON'T support index.

By the way, searching on the Internet, I can only find ways to set excel cell range to XValue, but didn't find how to get the XValue.  I really appreciate if anyone can advise.

```
Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)book.Worksheets[a];
Excel.ChartObject chartObj = (Excel.ChartObject)worksheet.ChartObjects(1);
if (chartObj != null)
{
   Excel.Chart chart = (Excel.Chart)chartObj.Chart;
   var s = (Excel.Series)chart.SeriesCollection(1);
   object obj = s.XValues;
   //How to get s.XValues[1], s.XValues[2], s.XValues[3]...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var chart = chartObj.Chart as Excel.Chart;
var s = chart.SeriesCollection(1) as Excel.Series;

var xValues = (s.XValues as object) as Array;

foreach (var xVal in xValues)
{
    MessageBox.Show(xVal.ToString());
}
```

and also [What is this `Object[*]` type I get with COM interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4539231/2140173)