# Break all links in Excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I want to break all links within an excel workbook using c# via a VSTO addin and convert the formulas to hardcoded data.

EDIT UPDATE:
Code iterates through each link fine but the link is not broken, the breaklink line executes but nothing happens?

```
Array links = (Array)((object)invoiceBook.LinkSources());
if (links != null)
{

    foreach (string link in (Array)links)
    {
        invoiceBook.BreakLink(link, Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Array links = (Array)invoiceBook.LinkSources(Excel.XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this `Object[*]` type I get with COM interop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4539231/11683)

Comment: @GSerg - 1st comment yes, no impact the only links in my workbook as xllinks. Second comment (thx) - this has helped me to get the iteration working - see update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the wb.Breaklink function does not work with certain formulas - in my case SUMIFs. I was able to get the breaklink function to work by adding a named range with a value of 1 then adding to the end of my sumif formula * namedrange. Excel then recongnised the external link and removed it effectively