# C# Shift entire array by 1

Tags: c#

I wanted to shift the entire array by one. Example: if the array goes from [0] to [19] i want it to be from [1] to [20], [0] dissapears.

**Current approach (it's wrong):**

```
   shiftRight(operationsList.ToArray()));


    public Operation3D[] shiftRight(Operation3D[] arr)
    {
        Operation3D[] demo = new Operation3D[arr.Length];

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            demo[i] = arr[i - 1];
        }

        demo[0] = arr[demo.Length - 1];

        return demo;
    }
```

Comment: What does "it's wrong" mean?

Comment: By "dissapears", do you mean turns to `null`?

Comment: Keep in mind that "shift" has a pretty particular meaning when talking about arrays/hashes (that is, remove and return an element from the beginning of an array).

Comment: You cannot make 0 disappear, as that index is always going to exist in an array with at least 1 element. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you're trying to make a non-zero lower bound array, reconsider. If you're just trying to make room to insert a new item at index 0, then that's another thing entirely. Your question isn't clear enough to make the distinction about your intent. You can read about non-zero lower bound arrays [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446/net-arrays-with-lower-bound-0). Otherwise, clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the elements to the right will require a new array because of the resizing. There is no way to make index `0` disappear. It will have to exist but it can be `null`.

The code below will accomplish this:

```
public Operation3D[] shiftRight(Operation3D[] arr)
{
    Operation3D[] result = new Operation3D[arr.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, result, 1, arr.Length);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: His code attempt sort of looks like he's trying to rotate the array, even if his words say otherwise. **If** a rotation is desired, this code gets you very close but you need to move the last array position to temporary storage, perform the array copy using arr.Length-1 as the number of elements, then move the value in temporary storage to index 0.

Comment: @EricJ. I agree, I didn't know which way to go with it. I had to choose one.