# VBA array with lower boundary > 0 passed to .NET

Tags: c#, excel, vba, windows, com

I have .NET Dll with a C# method, which I use in Excel VBA. It's being called through a COM-wrapper from VBA. The method takes among others, two double arrays as arguments.

When the double arrays are defined in VBA with a lower boundary of 1, and being passed to the C# method though COM, Excel fails with following error:

**Runtime error 5** *(Invalid procedure call or argument)*

Although it may sound crazy, I would want to be able to pass a VBA/COM array with lower boudary of 1 to C# .NET. Is this possible?

This is how the C# function is declared:

```
public double LinearInterpolation(
                                double[] psaXvector,
                                double[] psaYvector,
                                double Xvalue)
{
```

The COM-wrapper in C#

```
 [Guid("CE93D637-0673-4EBC-8FFA-6CE162959262")]
 [ComVisible(true)]
 [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
 public interface IMixedTools
 {
   [DispId(1)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double 
   LinearInterpolation(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]double[] psaXvector, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]double[] psaYvector, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]double Xvalue);
```

This is what the generated .tlh file looks like

```
struct __declspec(uuid("ce93d637-0673-4ebc-8ffa-6ce162959262"))
IMixedTools : IDispatch
{
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall LinearInterpolation (
    /*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY * psaXvector,
    /*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY * psaYvector,
    /*[in]*/ double Xvalue,
    /*[out,retval]*/ double * pRetVal ) = 0;
```

The calling VBA code

```
  Dim mixu As Object
  Set mixu = CreateObject("TlibCOM.CMixedTools")
  Dim Xarr() As Double
  Dim Yarr() As Double
  ReDim Xarr(1 To 4) As Double
  ReDim Yarr(1 To 4) As Double
  Dim x As Double

  Xarr(1) = 1
  Xarr(2) = 2
  Xarr(3) = 5
  Xarr(4) = 7.5

  Yarr(1) = 14
  Yarr(2) = 9
  Yarr(3) = 4
  Yarr(4) = -3

  x = 4
  result = mixu.LinearInterpolation(Xarr, Yarr, x)

  Set mixu = Nothing
```

If I define the arrays with lower boundaries of 0, the function will work. But I have a quite large legacy codebase where arrays may be defined either with 0 or 1 as lower boundary of arrays, so the functions having arrays as arguments would need to be able to handle this.

The C# .NET DLL is a library of methods, replacing legacy ATL COM functions. Previously this was not an issue whether the double array passed from VBA was having a low boundary of 1 or 0.

Is there a way to go round this limitation, so that VBA can pass an array with the low boundary of 1, to C# methods in a DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by "previously"? WHEN was "previously"? What changed? Do you mean the problem occurred when you moved to C#? As far as I know, C# has always supported *only* 0-based arrays. VBA supports 1- or 0-based. About ATL I don't know...

Comment: here are some hints about what works, and what doesn't.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446/net-arrays-with-lower-bound-0  with ToArray() you can always create a quick 0-based copy of your array, if this is already sufficient.

Comment: When you use an array in VBA with lower boundary 1 there is still an index zero with no data.  So if you are passing the array to c# nothing will change.  c# arrays have a GetLowerBound property just like VBA,  Are you sure you fully compiled before changing.  Try again to be sure it works with an lower boundary zero.

Comment: @CindyMeister With previously, I meant with the legacy ATL COM function. Peeking into the header file of that project reveals that the same function has the same COM interface, i.e. arrays defined as SAFEARRAY*.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried and it works fine with lower boundary set to zero. It compiles also when it's set to 1. But during runtime I get that runtime error 5. It doesn't even enter into the DLL file, so that I can debug it. It just bounces off, as somehow the interface doesn't match.

Comment: Found a hint at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-arrays where it reads: "Multidimensional, or nonzero-bound safe arrays, can be marshaled into managed code if the method signature produced by Tlbimp.exe is modified to indicate an element type of ELEMENT_TYPE_ARRAY instead of ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY. Alternatively, you can use the /sysarray switch with Tlbimp.exe to import all arrays as System.Array objects".

Comment: You have to change the parameter type to `Array` and state the SafeArraySubType in the attribute.  Use the Array methods to access the array in your C# code (GetLowerBound, GetUpperBound, GetValue).

Comment: @HansPassant You mean the C# core function has to use System.Array instead of double[]?

Comment: Yes.  You declared LinearInterpolation() with double[] parameters, that needs to be Array parameters to let the VBA code pass non-conformant arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the method signature in the COM-wrappers Interface to using Array instead of double[] and defining SafeArraySubType:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double 
   LinearInterpolation(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_R8 )]Array psaXvector, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_R8 )]Array psaYvector, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]double Xvalue);
```

This allows a COM Safearray being passed to the method being defined from [n to m] where n > 0.

Before the array is passed on to the core C# method, it's converted from Array to double[] in the COM-wrapper Class

```
public double LinearInterpolation(Array psaXvector, Array psaYvector, double Xvalue)
{
    double[] xarray = psaXvector.OfType<double>().ToArray();
    double[] yarray = psaYvector.OfType<double>().ToArray();
    return _mix.LinearInterpolation(xarray, yarray, Xvalue);
}
```