# C# - why does Array.Clone() need a cast?

Tags: c#, arrays

The [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=net-5.0) show that C#'s Array.Clone() method returns type `object`:

```
public object Clone ();
```

and indeed the example they give includes a cast.

eg

```
int[] myClone1 =        (new int[2]).Clone();   // Type error
int[] myClone2 = (int[])(new int[2]).Clone();   // All good
```

Why does Clone() return `object` instead of the expected type ?

Comment: Because the method predates generics and returns an object, simple as that really. You can achieve the same with `ToArray()` which will not need to be cast

Comment: that was fast! that sounds plausible. thanks. cheers for the `ToArray()` tip as well, I'd missed that.

Comment: Also this method works on an array with any dimensions, which are a little trickier to deal with (for historical reason)

Comment: including arrays with non-zero bounds :) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446/net-arrays-with-lower-bound-0)

Answer (score 0):

Because `.Clone()` returns an `object` not an `int`. Therefore it needs a cast to be of type `int`.

Comment: My real question is why the language is designed so that `Clone()` returns `object` rather than (in this case) `int[]`.

Comment: I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

`.Clone()` is an implementation of `ICloneable.Clone`, then it must return an `Object`.
Microsoft docs mentioned refer to it in "Implements".

Answer (score 0):

A shallow copy of an Array copies only the elements of the Array, whether they are reference types or value types, but it does not copy the objects that the references refer to. The references in the new Array point to the same objects that the references in the original Array point to.

In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.

The clone is of the same Type as the original Array.

```
int[] array = new int[2] { 12, 13 };
int[] arrClone = (int[])array.Clone();

//or
object arrClone1 = array.Clone();

//or
object arrClone2 = array;
foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<int>)arrClone2)
{
    int x = item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is not about deep vs. shallow copies.  It's about why the language is designed such that the return type of `Clone()` is awkward.

Comment: see this link:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/interview-question/whats-the-difference-between-the-systemarraycopyto-and-systemarrayclone222. This link provides a comprehensive explanation that was very useful to me.