# Array creation with wrong start index, why?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, new-operator, .net-8.0

I have a small piece of code in .net 8

```
private byte[,,] GetBytes<T>(T[,] imageArray, int dataSize)
{
    int yDimension = imageArray.GetLength(0); 
    int xDimension = imageArray.GetLength(1);

    byte[,,] result = new byte[yDimension, xDimension, dataSize];
```

function is used inside of for loop

in debug I see that x and y Dimension is 1024 and dataSize is 2,
sometimes result array is created like byte[1024, 219..1242, 2]
Any ideas why this can happens ?

[image: debug]

I googled a lot but nothing related ..

Comment: "sometimes result array is created like byte[1024, 219..1242, 2]" - how did you come to this conclusion? What observation did you make that suggested that index range?

Comment: @PeterB I see that in debug in VS (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.8.0 Preview 6.0), and also I have a line after initialization that try to acces result[0,0,0] to set an value and in this line throws an error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I add a debug image on post

Comment: On further investigation, I learned that the 'usual' 1-dim array is a different type in the CLR compared to multi-dim arrays. The 1-dim type seems to actually have a fixed lowerbound of 0, and the multi-dim type can apparantly use lowerbounds that are > 0. This *still* does not explain why this happens (you never specify a lower bound), but at least it now seems that .NET makes it possible, where I first believed it wasn't even possible. Sources: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69082566/1220550) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34195/Non-Zero-Based-Arrays-and-Interface).

Comment: Tip: Visual Studio is already at 17.8.3, please update it. Previews can be buggy! We can't see if you are also using a preview of .NET 8, so after updating VS check and make sure you are using the [latest supported version](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) of that too.

Comment: @PeterB with this changes works .. hm 

byte[,,] result = (byte[,,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), new int[] { yDimension, xDimension, dataSize }, new int[] { 0, 0, 0 });

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It'll be very hard to help you without that.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? c# Multi dimensional arrays are not great for representing images, since they are column major instead of row major. So you either need to index like `img[y,x]`, transpose it, or use another image type. If you intend to save/load your image you want to convert it to `byte[]`/`span<byte>`/stream, since that is how binary data is represented. Ideally, saving/loading can be done with a simple memory copy.